# How to send java application metrics (Garbage Collection, JVM) from a Kubernetes pod to DataDog

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

I am running a java application on a pod in the Kubernetes cluster. this is monitored by DataDog. so far pod logs are appearing in the datadog console. Now I got a new requirement to collect application metrics like Garbage collection and JVM metrices. I am looking for the help in the same.
Should I need to run a sidecar container or Does datadog has the capability to collect application metrices by tuning some parameters in the Kubernetes deployments. Your help much appreciated.

I have setup datadog in the Kubernetes cluster. at this moment it is sending pod logs to datadog. now I would like to send application metrics like JVM metrics and Garbage collection.